# Merge Sort returns the same array in Python

Tags: python-2.7, mergesort

for merge sort i wrote this code:
I have tested merge function that works correctly. but in mergeSort function i coudn't handle the arrays. it returns the same list as the input list.

```
def mergeSort(a):
    l, h = 0, len(a)-1
    mid = (l+h)/2
    if (l<h-1):                 #the lowest length must be 2
        mergeSort(a[l:mid+1])
        mergeSort(a[mid+1:h+1])
    return merge(a[l:mid+1],a[mid+1:h+1])

def merge(a,b):
    n_a = len(a)
    n_b = len(b)
    c = [[] for i in range(n_a + n_b)]
    i,j,k=0,0,0
    while (i<n_a and j<n_b):
        if a[i]<b[j]:
            c[k] = a[i]
            i += 1
        else:
            c[k]= b[j]
            j += 1
        k += 1
    while(i<n_a):
        c[k] = a[i]
        k+=1
        i+=1
    while(j< n_b):
        c[k] = b[j]
        k+=1
        j+=1
    return c
```

Comment: `a[l:mid+1]` is a slice. It copies the content of a. a is unchanged.

Comment: you should do `frst = mergeSort(a[l:mid+1]) sec = mergeSort(a[mid+1:h+1]) return merge(frst, sec)`

Comment: as a side note `c = [[] for i in range(n_a + n_b)]` is useless and incorrect (it does not have any impact of the algorithm, but it does not make sense). use `c = []`, then remove k, and use `c.append(...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rewrite merge as so:

```
def mergeSort(a):
    h = len(a)
    mid = h / 2
    if h >= 2:
        return merge(mergeSort(a[:mid]), mergeSort(a[mid:]))
    else:
        return a
```

A few notes:

- `l` is always 0, might as well remove it
- `h` is `len(a) - 1`,  but then you use `h + 1`, might as well use `h = len(a)`
- Actually writting `h >= 2` makes it clearer that you need at least 2 items in your list
- `mid` can be `len(a) / 2`.
- when taking the complete beginning/end of an array in a slice, the first/last bound is not required